# SMBus adapter not used as i2c device

Tags: linux, hardware

I have a PCI device which has a SMBus controller function:

```
~> lspci | grep SMBus
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 03)
```

Looking at the corresponding sys path, I find:

```
~> cat /sys/class/i2c-adapter/i2c-0/name
SMBus I801 adapter at efa0
```

However, this adapter does not show up in `i2cdetect`:

```
~> i2cdetect -l
~>
```

There is also no path `/sys/class/i2c-dev` and none for a device.

The kernel log doesn't show any errors when (re)loading the module:

```
~> dmesg | grep smb
[43422.836864] i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.3: SPD Write Disable is set
[43422.836892] i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.3: SMBus using PCI interrupt
[43423.713920] rmi4_smbus 0-002c: registering SMbus-connected sensor
```

This is a Lenovo T450s running NixOS, currently on version 5.6.7 of the linux kernel.
There are no hardware devices disabled in the BIOS.

I'm grateful for any tips that help to make the i2c bus usable.